# DocuSign: templatesApi.createEditViewGetting() responds with 400 Error

Tags: docusignapi

When I call templatesApi.createEditView(templatedId) with templateId of shared template, as a user with

USER PERMISSIONS: **Templates: Create**

I'm getting 400 Error:
`{"errorCode":"USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_TEMPLATE","message":"This user is not authorized to access the requested template. User does not have rights to edit shared templates."}.`

But actually from DocuSign account I can edit shared with me templates.

[DocuSign account edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJZaK.png)

Is anybody knows, why I can't do it from API????

Tried to search the problem, but for now any luck.

Answer (score 0):

The `templateId` you provided in this request is mostly likely for a template that was created by a user who has a different userId than **userId** for the **accessToken** you use to make API calls.

Make sure:

1. Your are using a template from the **developer env**, not production env.
2. You are using a template from the **same account** that you are using to make API calls.
3. You are using a template that was created by the same **user** that you are using to make API calls.

There's a way to share templates between users (in the same account) but you have to explicitly [share the template](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301=&bundleId=xry1643227563338&topicId=lrh1578456401532.html&_LANG=enus), it's not shared automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Actually, I have 2 account users (Admin, User1 with USER PERMISSIONS: Templates: Create). I've created a template by Admin, created shared folders, and shared it with User 1. 

As User1 I can see that template in the shared folder and I can edit it. But  I can't edit it from API (templatesApi.createEditView(templatedId)) using User1 userId and its' templatedId.

Comment: Interesting, I would suggest to try to record your API calls when you edit it from the web app. You can see what API calls the web app is making and make the same yourself. I suspect you need to add something in the API to tell it the template is shared. Can you try it?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJYTDcc7cZw